# Prevent elements not being properly loaded in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I have this whatsapp bot and I need to send messages frequently while the user does other work, so the program opens chrome and then the user overlays it with another window "chrome window, file explorer or whatever", the problem is that on windows it works just fine, but on macOS, if you don't focus on the whatsapp window, the program execute wrong commands like not seeing an element. Does anybody know a solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try running the Selenium script in headless mode. This can resolve your issue.

Comment: I also found this, but I am looking for a more efficient solution, this will be my last reserve

Comment: Why this is not a good solution for you? Why do you think it is not efficient?

Comment: I want to show the window so that it can be monitored

Comment: hey @Prophet, I used the headless way, I was waiting for an element to appear, but it never did, is there something wrong or what?

Comment: Well, without basic debugging information it's difficult to say what happened, but I guess you did not set the screen size for the headless mode. The default headless screen size if significantly smaller than in regular mode. Please let me know if that helped and next time please open a new, separate question for that. I'm definitely not 24/7 here. Also, there are a lot of other people here who may help :)

Comment: Please let me know if my guess worked.

Comment: I actually tried to reviel the whatsapp window and see what's happening, and I found whatsapp asking me to update google chrome. I updated my question and added a picture of it

Comment: I tried to update  but it gave me this error "An error occurred while checking for updates: Update check failed to start (error code 4: 0x80070005 -- system level)."

Comment: Well, you know, this changes the question totally...

Comment: Do you suggest asking another question

Comment: Now, this is definitely NOT a Selenium issue

Comment: Looks like you should

Comment: I posted another question if you have any suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370901/whatsapp-asking-for-updating-chrome-version)