# Whatsapp asking for updating chrome version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open whatsapp with selenium and python, it was working fine until today. In headless or non, whatsapp is now asking to update chrome, when I try to do so, Chrome throws this error:

```
An error occurred while checking for updates: Update check failed to start (error code 4: 0x80070005 -- system level).
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to delete my saved chrome profile and recreate it.